# ¿Qué era exactamente el "algo" de los hidalgos?

Tags: etimología, historia

Partiendo de la definición de la palabra, tenemos:

> **[hidalgo, ga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KIqVMrl)**
>
> De *fidalgo*, y este del ant. *fijo dalgo*; literalmente 'hijo
>   de algo'.
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que por linaje pertenecía al estamento inferior de la nobleza.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a un hidalgo. *Familia hidalga.*
> 3. adj. De ánimo generoso y noble. *Actitud hidalga.*

Siempre me he preguntado qué era ese "algo". Curiosamente, en la RAE aparece esta definición:

> **[algo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1nUry2t)**
>
> Del lat. *alĭquod*.
>
> 3. m. desus. Hacienda, caudal. Era u. t. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing. *El magnífico debe ser muy sabio porque sepa cómo ha de partir sus algos.*

Ya en 1611, Covarrubias explicaba en su obra que:

> "*E porque estos fueron escogidos de buenos lugares e con algo [...] por esso los llamaron fijos de algo, que muestra tanto como fijos de bien.*"

Es decir, vuelve a equiparar tener "algo" con tener bienes. Esta frase aparece también en el Diccionario de Autoridades (tomo I, 1726), aclarando además que:

> Vale lo própio que substáncia, bienes, hacienda, caudal.

Luego, **¿un "hijo de algo" era simplemente alguien que provenía de una familia con bienes (algo)? ¿Todo se reducía a un título que se podía comprar con dinero? ¿Podía ese "algo" ser otra cosa aparte de los bienes o la hacienda?**

Comment: Corominas tiene un artículo interesantísimo sobre la otra parte, es decir, de dónde viene el **hijo** en _hijo de algo_.

Comment: Me viene a la cabeza la expresión _ser algo_ en algún ámbito: ser importante, rico... Pero lo que me ha gustado es descubrir en el [Diccionario de Dudas y Dificultades de la Lengua Española, de Manuel Seco](https://es.scribd.com/doc/151700987/RAE-Seco-Manuel-Diccionario-de-dudas-y-dificultades-de-la-lengua-espanola) menciones a la palabra [_hijodalgo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KOHAZ84). Sobre la pregunta en sí: ¿qué más podría ser? En la edad media, la propiedad era lo que distinguía e iba íntimamente ligada con el poder.

Comment: @fedorqui como he dicho en otras ocasiones, a veces la respuesta es un simple "no". Igual en un principio los hidalgos se originaron simplemente como gente de bien (con bienes), y posteriormente se permitieron hidalgos de otra forma (por cuestiones de honor, valentía, etc.). Igual la pregunta ha sido una forma velada de preguntar qué significaba ser un _hidalgo_, ahora que me doy cuenta, sólo que me he liado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El artículo de la Wikipedia sobre [Hidalgo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidalgo) aporta luz sobre el asunto, mencionando precisamente a Covarrubias:

> Ignota, se desconoce el origen cierto, Covarrubias dice se sabe que de hidalgo vino hidalguía, que comúnmente se refería al hombre bien nacido, existiendo el fem. hidalga, que su uso es muy propio de España. Fidalgo se dijo por el latín fide «fe»1 que vale por confianza y lealtad.
>
> Esto no obsta que hubieran varias acepciones que se arraigan en lo antiguo, según Sebastián de Covarrubias en su tiempo se consideraban estas:
>
> - La Itálica o romana que dice acaso proceda del Ius italicum de la Antigua Roma, exención y nobleza que se concedía primero por el pueblo romano, después por los emperadores y también se obtenía por compra.
> - La cristiana traída de un episodio de San Pablo quien dio a entender a un tribuno que había heredado la nobleza de sus padres y que por ello no solo era algo sino **hijo de algo, de aquí se interpretaba que *algo* vale por nobleza, bondad o bienes**.<sup>1</sup>
> - En la acepción Goda se dijo que es voz corrompida de 'fijo de Godo' - hijo de Godo o filgod - y que transmutadas consonares derivó hasta 'fidalgo'. El fundamento sería que quedaron muy pocos nobles y realeza Goda refugiados en las montañas e iniciada la reconquista estos eran muy estimados en España.
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Sebastián de Covarrubias-Horozco - Tesoro dela lengua castellana o española. Ed. 1611, pp. 401 rev. - 403 voz 'FIDALGO'</sub>

Por tanto, todo parece indicar que ese *algo* del que podía disponer un hidalgo era cualquiera de los elementos que daban poder en la Edad Media:

- bienes: tierras y/o dinero (iban de la mano).
- nobleza: poder, seguramente asociado de forma íntima a los bienes.
- bondad: no sé si asociarlo con la iglesia pues no veo ninguna referencia entre la hidalguía y el estamento eclesiástico.

El tema de la *bondad* requiere un capítulo aparte. Veo por ejemplo que es un concepto que se menciona con frecuencia en *El Quijote de La Mancha*. Además, el mismo artículo de la Wiki añade más referencias a ella:

> En la Partida Segunda, la Ley XII7 del Título XXI,8 establece dos maneras de llegar a la nobleza:
>
> - Por saber, es decir, mediante el conocimiento y la práctica de Ciencias y Artes Liberales.
> - Por bondad de costumbres - more nobilium -.

No he encontrado una descripción clara de qué calificaba el *more nobilium*.

Answer (score 0):

El [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KIqVMrl) recoge:

> **hidalgo de bragueta**
>   1. m. Padre que, por haber tenido en legítimo matrimonio siete hijos varones consecutivos, adquiría el derecho de hidalguía.
>
> **hidalgo de privilegio**
>   1. m. hidalgo que lo era por compra o merced real.

Por lo que parece que también se podía ser hidalgo por ser prolífico, por compra o merced real.

> **hidalgo de gotera**
>   1. m. hidalgo que únicamente en un pueblo gozaba de los privilegios de su hidalguía, de tal manera que los perdía al mudar su domicilio.

y que la condición de hidalgo podía estar reducida a un solo pueblo

Comment: Sí, esos usos los tenía localizados en el DRAE. El hidalgo de privilegio si se obtenía por compra corrobora que el título se podía adquirir. Si se conseguía por merced real, ¿a qué era debido? ¿A algún tipo de gesta o hazaña? Espero que no fuera solo por la "hazaña" de tener siete hijos varones seguidos... :) Mi pregunta iba más bien encaminada a saber si la palabra "algo" pudo haber tenido algún otro sentido más orientado hacia el honor que hacia los bienes, para dar sentido a los hidalgos que lo eran por algo más que por tener dinero.